# SecureString in UWP usage

Tags: c#, uwp, securestring

I'm trying to keep some strings safe in memory and Installed the SecureString Nuget package in a UWP targeting 10240. Using it is pretty easy:

```
SecureString secureStr = new SecureString();
for (int i = 0; i < someString.Length; i++)
{
    secureStr.AppendChar(someString[i]);
}
secureStr.MakeReadOnly();
```

But in order to access the content I have to use:

```
 IntPtr stringPointer = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(secureStringObj);
string normalString = Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(stringPointer);
Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR(stringPointer);
```

But in UWP there is not such method in the Marshal class `SecureStringToBSTR` any other ways to read the content of a SecureString?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the `SecureStringMarshal` class to get a pointer, and then the regular `Marshal.PtrToStringXXXX` methods to read it as a string etc.

Comment: Sorry, It worked in Debug but it breaks and crases if you compile it with .net Native.